# Regex for clearly single line words with wildcards in Swift

Tags: ios, regex

I'm attempting to construct a regex string in Swift 4 that gets characters at the start of a line where some are known and others aren't.

Let's say I've got a text file with line breaks for each word that reads as follows:

```
pucker
tuckered
duckerdinger
sucker punch
```

I'd like to get every word that contains "cker" in it that's 1 to 8 characters long.

I'm attempting to use this statement `^..cker..{1,8}` as my RegEx string. All I'm getting is a partial match in Patterns (a Mac App), but [Regex101.com's](https://regex101.com/r/LQcc3i/1) saying no match, and most importantly, Xcode says I'm using an invalid regex. I've also tried `^(..cker..)` and a bazillion other variations.

What am I screwing up and how do I fix it? What I'm trying to do seems like it would be super simple, but I've wasted more time than I care to admit fiddling with it.

**Update:**

This has been the best I've been able to get so far...

`"\\b..cker.."`, but I'm only able to get words that are exactly 8 characters long. I'd like to capture words that contain "cker" that are the 3rd, 4th, 5th, and 6th letters while capturing words up to 8 characters long.

Comment: Words or strings? See [`^(?=.{1,8}$).*cker.*`](https://regex101.com/r/ZCsCCV/1). Or words in text? See [`\b(?=\w{1,8}\b)\w*cker\w*`](https://regex101.com/r/ZCsCCV/2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\b(?=.*cker)[a-zA-Z]{1,8}\b
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LQcc3i/4)

**Explanation:**

- `\b` - matches a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `(?=.*cker)` - [Positive Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure our string should contain the character sequence `cker`
- `[a-zA-Z]{1,8}` - Matches 1 to 8 occurrences of a letter
- `\b` - matches a word boundary

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.